# 'Cannot Install Constraint', reason: 'No common superview between views

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class RecordButton: UIView {
     let box = UIView()
     let container = UIView()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
         container.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
         make.width.equalTo(200)
         make.height.equalTo(200)
         make.center.equalTo(self.container)
         }
    box.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(container).offset(50)
        make.left.equalTo(container).offset(50)
        make.bottom.equalTo(container).offset(-50)
        make.right.equalTo(container).offset(-50)
        make.center.equalTo(container)
    }
    self.addSubview(container)
    container.addSubview(box)
    setColor()

    }
    func setColor() {
         self.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
         self.box.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }

}
```

Why is it showing this error? Is there any other way to execute this? Any Suggestion?. The centre.equalTo creates this error. I am new to swift and trying to implement SnapKit framework

Comment: try adding the views before you install constraints on them (move the `sip_makeConstraints` block to after you've added the views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means your views or any controller should be in common view. 
For example, There is view A having two buttons  say X and Y and view B have two buttons P and K then you can set constraint of P and K respected to it's super view B not with respect to view A.

If there are multiple super views then make sure that you have given proper constraint to every super view. then only endpoint view's constraints will be satisfied.

**Uodate:**

First add box in container and container in it's superview then set the constraints. and make sure that you are getting center in `self.container` and `container` for `container view` and `box view` respectively.  If you are setting `top,bottom,leading and trailing` then not need to set center also!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I know i am being silly but can you explain that with respect to my code? That would be great.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot:)